# React Native Flatlist not refreshing data on pull up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my posts page code, it fetches post titles from my API on load and this works perfect. The problem is that once it's loaded if a new post is added to API and I pull up to refresh it doesn't get new posts even though my onRefresh function works because I can trigger an alert in it.

The only way I can get new posts in API to show after they were loaded is by reloading the application itself.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: true,
      data: []
    };
  }

fetchData = () => {
    const url = 'myAPIurl';
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(res => {
        const arrayData = [...this.state.data, ...res]
        this.setState({
          data: arrayData,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ refreshing: false });
      });
  };


handleRefresh = () => {
  this.setState(
    {
      refreshing: true
    },
    () => {
      this.fetchData();
      alert('Pulled Up to Refresh');
    }
  );
};


  render() {
    return (

<View>
      <FlatList
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          />
        }
        horizontal={false}
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
    <View>
          <Text>{item.title.rendered}</Text>
     </View>
        }
      />
</View>
    );
  }
}
```

When I pull up to refresh I get this warning: Two children with same key. Keys should be unique. This is weird because each post ID is unique. And even with this warning, the new posts that are in API don't show unless I re-load the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `handleRefresh` function like below:

```
handleRefresh = () => {
this.setState(
{
  refreshing: true,
  data:[]
},
() => {
  this.fetchData();
  alert('Pulled Up to Refresh');
  }
 );
};
```